# Jquery is not adding class

Tags: jquery

But if I try adding anything other than the Selected, it's working.**

I updated the code to

But still the same.

Comment: in your js function WallMenu() you remove and then add the same class

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this, ".CatList li")
$(this, ".CatList .Selected .SubCatList li")
```

Those should be turned around:

```
$(".CatList li", this)
$(".CatList .Selected .SubCatList li", this)
```

When providing two parameters, you're saying: "Search for this (first param), **inside** this (second param)".

========= **UPDATE**

My code above explains when you want to search "within" your selection. But when looking a bit better at your code, I assume you want to add the class to the element you clicked on.

If that's the case, you don't need to subselect, but just provide the `$(this)` as selector.

```
$(".CatList li").click(function () {
    $(".CatList li").removeClass("Selected");
    $(this).addClass("Selected");
});
```

Comment: it did not work. still having the same problem.
It always works for CatList. But its not working with SubCatList. It's not adding the class "Selected".

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$(".CatList .Selected .SubCatList li").click(function () {` to `$(".CatList ul.SubCatList li").click(function () {`

Answer (score 0):

At last I just able to understand the glich.
when subcatlist li element is clicked (which is on catlist) fires that catlist li is clicked.
so, first it removes all the selected class for every li element within the catlist (including the subcatlist li).

Now, on the first function selected class is added to the catlist li. so catlist li item remains ok. but li item in subcatlist don't have the selected class. best way to get around this i think is to use a different class.